# Image upload on Phonegap / framework 7 app

Tags: image, upload, html-framework-7, phonegap

I'm creating this app with Phonegap and Framework 7.
In one of my views, i wanted to have a image upload button and i implemented the following code:

```
<script>

function selectPhoto() {

        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
        function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
        { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, }
        );

    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://pedrofidalgo.pt/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

</script>

<button class="btngaleria" onclick="selectPhoto();" style="margin-top:3vh; background-color: #5f919d;"> Upload image </button>
```

I then have a php file on a web server with this code:

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/uploads/sitios".$new_image_name);
?>
```

I tried building the APK and when i click the button it simply doesn't do anything. When i tried the app in the browser, the console says that the function i'm calling with the button (selectPhoto) is not defined.. can someone give some guidance please?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code

```
function fail(error) 
{
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
```

should be

```
function fail(error) 
{
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
```